# Issues with query to match all joined rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will act as my search function.

Let's say I have three tables: `Places`, `PlaceFeatures` and a lookup table `PlacesPlaceFeatures`

I am currently passing two parameters to my stored procedure, `@Query NVARCHAR(50)` and `@FeaturesFilter VARCHAR(50)`. The `@Query` parameter contains the keyword(s) and `@FeaturesFilter` contains a comma separated list of `PlaceFeatureID`'s to match against.

To use the comma-separated list, I've implemented a `StringToTable` splitting function which is a table-valued function.

Currently, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   p.Id, p.Name
FROM 
   Places p
INNER JOIN 
   PlacesPlaceFeatures ppf ON ppf.PlaceId = p.Id
INNER JOIN 
   StringToTable(@FeaturesFilter, ',') pf ON pf.Data = ppf.PlaceFeatureId
WHERE 
   FREETEXT(p.*, @Query) AND Deleted = 0
```

Which kinda works. Because of the `INNER JOIN`, it will match any places that contain ANY of the `PlaceFeatureID`'s I pass through. What I would like it to do is match only if ALL place features exist...

I can't really add all of the place features as individual parameters to the query, as this is designed to be dynamic...

Is there a way to achieve what I want with relative performance within SQL Server, or am I better shifting my search logic to something like LUCENE.NET?

Thanks for your input :)

Cheers, 
Justin

Comment: You **do know** that as of SQL Server **2008**, the preferred way to pass multiple values to a stored procedure would be the [table-valued parameters (TVP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28SQL.100%29.aspx) ? That would save you the trouble of the string-to-table parsing of comma-separated strings.....

Comment: No, I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know of that feature...

Comment: you could always count the number of matches and if the count = the number of parameters passed, then you know it matched them all.  (if you have duplicates, you'd have to use distinct)